# Join with table and sub query in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00933

I don't understand what is wrong with this query. It is giving me a compile time error of "command not ended properly".

The inner query is giving me four records.

```
select WGN3EVENTPARTICIPANT.EVENTUID 
from 
    (Select WGN_V_ADDRESS_1.ADDRESSUID1 as add1,
            WGN_V_ADDRESS_1.ADDRESSUID2 as add2 
     from WGN3USER inner join 
          WGN_V_ADDRESS_1 on WGN_V_ADDRESS_1.USERID=wgn3user.USERID 
      where WGN3USER.USERNAME='FIRMWIDE\khuraj'
    ) as ta
    ,WGN3EVENTPARTICIPANT 
 where (ta.ADDRESSUID1=WGN3EVENTPARTICIPANT.ADDRESSUID1) AND    
       (ta.ADDRESSUID2=WGN3EVENTPARTICIPANT.ADDRESSUID2)
```

I am running it in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

You should change where clause to use fields alias:

```
 where (ta.add1=WGN3EVENTPARTICIPANT.ADDRESSUID1) AND    
       (ta.add2=WGN3EVENTPARTICIPANT.ADDRESSUID2)
```

**EDITED**

Try to remove `as` reserved word in table aliases:

```
) as ta -> ) ta
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, your original code sample contains several bugs.  However the one which causes the specific error you're reporting (ORA-00933) is this.

In Oracle `AS` is only used for *column* aliases.  So you need to alias your inline view like this:

```
... where WGN3USER.USERNAME='FIRMWIDE\khuraj'
    )  ta
```

Answer (score 0):

'\' is an escape character which needs to be escaped:

Change `'FIRMWIDE\khuraj'` in `'FIRMWIDE\\khuraj'`

And the outer where-clause references the wrong aliases: `ta.ADDRESSUID1` instead of `ta.add1` and `ta.ADDRESSUID2` instead of `ta.add2`

Comment: but OP says that subquery runs ok ... ?

Answer (score 0):

```
select WGN3EVENTPARTICIPANT.EVENTUID 
from 
    (Select WGN_V_ADDRESS_1.ADDRESSUID1 as add1,
            WGN_V_ADDRESS_1.ADDRESSUID2 as add2 
     from WGN3USER inner join 
          WGN_V_ADDRESS_1 on WGN_V_ADDRESS_1.USERID=wgn3user.USERID 
      where WGN3USER.USERNAME='FIRMWIDE\khuraj'
    ) as ta
    left outer join WGN3EVENTPARTICIPANT on 
 ta.ADDRESSUID1=WGN3EVENTPARTICIPANT.ADDRESSUID1 AND
       ta.ADDRESSUID2=WGN3EVENTPARTICIPANT.ADDRESSUID2
```